# Firebase multi location updates "cost"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been wondering how costly the multi location updates are?

I am working with many different nodes so I will not have to read big data when I need a report for example.

Assuming I will have to update about 12 differnet locations (nodes) whenever I add item to my database, will it use too much resources or it's designed for such cases?

Comment: its depends on how you structure your data and data structure depends on how you will retrieve that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase **Realtime** Database uses websockets to exchange the information with database and client. Once the connection is established it sends and received information in this connection. Of course everything has its limit but I think 12 or 120 updates will not be problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific maximum of what you can do in a multi-location update.

If you have a problem with a specific multi-location update, post the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can have a look.